# How to handle additional multer file uploads from a NodeJS API perspective?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, multer

I am building a NodeJS API that speaks to MongoDB. I can't figure out how to handle multer file uploads via the API properly. I have a PATCH route that handles any JSON params passed to it and updates a document according to specified Id.

PATCH route:

```
app.route('/api/Vehicles/:vehicleId')
    .patch(upload.single('carFile'),clickHandler.updateId)
```

Document:

```
{
    "carDoc": [
        "http://localhost:3000/uploadsVehicle/2019-06-21T08:13:04.068Z_X5.jpg",
        "http://localhost:3000/uploadsVehicle/2019-06-21T08:38:03.562Z_X5.jpg"
    ],
    "_id": "5d0a039e16bf91332d968b46",
    "carNum": "XXX325",
    "carManager": "Gzegorz Tomasevic",
    "insuranceExp": "2021-06-06T00:00:00.000Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

The below function handles the PATCH requests perfectly fine, however as I now need to associate files to my mongo documents somehow, I have implemented that if a file is accessed by `req.file` then an array in the specified document which is `carDoc` is updated with a web link to the newly uploaded image/pdf/whatever. As you can see the below function checks if any files are being uploaded, executes the ops under if, and proceeds to execute an update for other fields in the document as I initially designed this to only handle PATCH requests. So if I want to upload a new file only and create a new link in the `carDoc` array I end up getting the 404 response as the `Vehicle.update` function does not see that I have pushed a new weblink into the `carDoc` array. Is there a way I can combine the two operations ($push and $set) so I can receive a single response which I could then handle properly? Thank you!

The request handler:

```
// modify doc by id
this.updateId = function (req, res) {

  const id = req.params.vehicleId;
  const updateObject = req.body;

  // if a file is uploaded add path to existing carDoc array
  if (req.file) {

    Vehicle.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: id}, {$push: {carDoc: ["http://localhost:3000/" + req.file.path]}})
     .exec()
     .then()

  }

  // update and error handling
  Vehicle.update({_id: id}, {$set: updateObject })
     .exec()
     .then(doc => {
        console.log(doc);
        if (doc.n === 0) {
           res.status(404).json({message: "document you are trying to modify does not exist."})
        }
        else {
           res.status(200).json({message: id +" document successfully modified.", changes: updateObject})
        }
     })
     .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
           error: err
        })
     });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way with `Promise.all([])`:

```
  // check if file is being uploaded
  var fileQuery = req.file ? Vehicle.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: id}, {$push: {carDoc: ["http://localhost:3000/" + req.file.path]}}) : Promise.resolve();
  // execute any other changes
  var bodyQuery = Vehicle.update({_id: id}, {$set: updateObject })

  // handle single response etc.
  Promise.all([fileQuery, bodyQuery])
  .then(result => {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [multer link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to understand, how multer npm is used in Node.JS.

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'dest_folder_path/' });
```

The fill will get stored at above destination location, then in your code update document path and then save it in mongodb.

Change below line in code.

```
Vehicle.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: id}, {$push: {carDoc: ["http://localhost:3000/" + dest_folder_path/foldername]}}
```

It means that file is stored on code server `http://localhost:3000/dest_folder_path`

Comment: I've got this sorted, my uploads work. I was asking if I could combine the 2 queries I'm making to receive a single response. Thanks